# Prestashop 1.6 get feature value of products from specific category

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to get the value of a specific feature of a product that is from a specific category. the id_category_default is 13 (Processors ) and the id_feature is 6 (Power(W)
the output i'm looking for should be something like this:

```
<ProcessorName><ValueOfFeature>
```

Untill now i've tried this:

```
 SELECT pl.name,fvl.value 

from ps_product_lang pl,ps_product p,ps_feature_value_lang fvl,ps_feature_value fv,ps_feature f,ps_feature_lang fl
where pl.id_product=p.id_product
and p.id_product in (SELECT id_product
             from ps_feature_product
             where id_feature in (select id_feature
                      from ps_feature
                      where id_feature = 6))
and pl.id_lang = 1
and pl.id_shop = 1
and p.id_shop_default=1
and p.id_category_default =13
and fvl.id_feature_value=fv.id_feature_value
and fv.id_feature=f.id_feature
and fvl.id_lang=1
and fl.id_feature =f.id_feature
and fl.id_lang=1
and f.id_feature=6
```

The output is this:

```
  <ProcessorName1><NameOfFeature><value 1 OfFeature>
  <ProcessorName1><NameOfFeature><value 2 OfFeature>
  <ProcessorName1><NameOfFeature><value 3 OfFeature>
  <ProcessorName1><NameOfFeature><value 4 OfFeature>

  <ProcessorName2><NameOfFeature><value 1 OfFeature>
  <ProcessorName2><NameOfFeature><value 2 OfFeature>
  <ProcessorName2><NameOfFeature><value 3 OfFeature>
  <ProcessorName2><NameOfFeature><value 4 OfFeature>

  <ProcessorName3><NameOfFeature><value 1 OfFeature1>
   etc
  <ProcessorName4><NameOfFeature><value 1 OfFeature1>
   etc
```

what i need is to get the feature that has id_feature=6 value for the specific product :

```
 <processorName1><valueOfFeature>
   <processorName2><valueOfFeature>
   <processorName3><valueOfFeature>
   <processorName4><valueOfFeature>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I had to look in the database schema more and managed to write the correct sql query